# Adding action to already presented UIAlertController

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uialertcontroller

I present `UIAlertController` with `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`. It has two actions initially, but after presenting the controller I have an asynchronous action that - when done - adds a new option to the sheet. Unfortunately adding new action doesn't affect presented `UIAlertController`. Additionally, when rotating the device I've got bug from the screenshot below. 
[image: Bug screenshot]
How to refresh already presented UIAlertController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Instead, provide all the actions you will ever need, and enable/disable them as appropriate.

Comment: Either that, or write your own alert-like view controller, as I have already demonstrated here: https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7 - at that point, it's your view and you can do anything you please.

Comment: Using `enable` property works, but it feels like bad UX. An indicator would be useful to show that the action is loading to be enabled.

Comment: Well, I answered that in my comment. Write your own presented view controller and put any interface you like. But don't try to mess with the built-in alert view; it is limited, and you must respect those limitations. In any case it seems like what you are doing here was _never_ a proper candidate for an alert view; you were misusing alert views the whole time.